# Transform Normal distribution into Hotelings $T^2$

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, transformation

I'm trying to understand why $ (\bar{x} - \mu)' \hat{\Sigma}_{\bar{x}}^{-1} (\bar{x} - \mu) $ follows a Hotelings T-squared distribution. Isn't the factor (n-1) missing, so that $ \hat{\Sigma}_{\bar{x}} $ follows a Wishart Distribution ?
Thank you.

[image: from Wikipedia]

Comment: Which wiki page is that?

Comment: Ist From  Wikipedia